# Ajax Form Submission Works But No Response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I'm using a menu that the user will select to delete a record from a database.  Below the menu, I have a table that displays the records from the database.  When I manually refresh the page, and the display results in the table show that the record was deleted, however, despite my best efforts, I can't seem to get any kind of message in my #results section.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="deleteAccountForm">
        <table>
            <thead>
                    <th>Delete Account</th>
                    <th></th>
            </thead>    
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><select name="deleteMenu" id="deleteMenu">
                    <?php
                    foreach($accounts as $key=>$value) { ?>
                        <option name="account_name" value="<?php echo $value['account_id_PK']; ?>"><?php echo $value['account_name']; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </select>

                    </td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

and my Javascript:

```
var delAccount = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#deleteAccountForm').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/functions.php",
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#results').html('processing');
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#results').html('failure');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#results').html(response);
        },
        timeout: 3000,
    });
};
```

and my PHP:

```
function delete_account() {

    require(ROOT_PATH . "/inc/database.php");

    $deleteAccount = $_POST['deleteMenu'];



    try {
        $results = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM account WHERE account_id_PK = ?");
        $results->bindValue(1, $deleteAccount);
        $results->execute();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "ERROR: Data could not be removed from the database. " . $e;
        exit;
    }
}
```

I also need to know how to run a function after this is completed to update the results in my display table  without having to refresh the page manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you do this in your javascript:

```
var delAccount = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the option that will be deleted to remove it
    // later on success.
    var opt  = $('#deleteMenu').children(':selected');

    var data = $('#deleteAccountForm').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/functions.php",
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#results').html('processing');
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#results').html('failure');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#results').html(response);
            // Remove the option
            opt.remove()
        },
        timeout: 3000,
    });
};
```

Regarding the message for #results, in your PHP I only see you respond if there's an error, unless the response for success is created and dispatched somewhere else?.

**[Edit]**

The response should be created, and in this case also sent, at the end of the `try` block. If the script gets to that part, it means everything went fine.

```
function delete_account() {
    require(ROOT_PATH . "/inc/database.php");
    $deleteAccount = $_POST['deleteMenu'];

    try {
        $results = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM account WHERE account_id_PK = ?");
        $results->bindValue(1, $deleteAccount);
        $results->execute();

        // If everything goes fine here, you can output the
        // success response.
        // Echo getAccounts() assuming it returns HTML (string).
        // Otherwise, setup your HTML and then echo it.
        echo getAccounts();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "ERROR: Data could not be removed from the database. " . $e;
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: no, the response is not created somewhere else.  How would I modify my PHP to send the correct response?

Comment: I have another PHP function called getAccounts, which I use to display the database records to the page.  How would I call that function at the end of my deleteAccount function in order to update the html table on the page?

Comment: I edited the answer. Let me know if that's not what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting the data to **"inc/functions.php"**. I assume that the **php code snippet** you have shown in the question is inside this page and you have called it in **ANYWAY**.
**Now first thing**, you have **not echoed** anything in the php file. ***whatever is echoed on the serer side php script, only is sent to the client in the variable "response" which you are using in the ajax: success method.***
Also, it is not clear where is your #result id tag in the html page.
My suggestion will be , you use "**jquery offline learning kit**"(search for this term on google and you will get link to download), it includes all the sample codes and you will learn how to effectively use ajax, and how to manipulate dom using jquery selector after successful or unsuccessful ajax submission.